# Apache Flink - End to End testing how to terminate input source

Tags: integration-testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming, end-to-end, data-stream

I've used apache flink in batch processing for a while but now we want to convert this batch job to a streaming job. The problem I run into is how to run end-to-end tests.

**How it worked in a batch job**

When using batch processing we created end-to-end tests using cucumber.

- We would fill up the hbase table we read from
- Run the batch job
- Wait for it to finish
- verify the result

**The problem in a streaming job**

We would like to do something similar with the streaming job except the streaming job does not really finish.

So:

- fill up the message queue we read from
- Run the streaming job.
- **Wait for it to finish (how?)**
- Verify the result

We could just wait 5 seconds after every test and assume everything has been processed but that would slow everything down a lot.

**Question:**

What are some ways or best practices to run end-to-end tests on a streaming flink job without forceable terminating the flink job after x seconds

Comment: This was also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441153/how-to-stop-a-flink-streaming-job-from-program/75961706#75961706

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Flink DataStream sources, if they are reading from a finite input, will inject a watermark with value LONG.MAX_VALUE when they reach the end, after which the job will be terminated.

The [Flink training exercises](http://training.data-artisans.com/) illustrate one approach to doing end-to-end testing of Flink jobs. I suggest cloning the [github repo](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises) and looking at how the tests are setup. They use a [custom source and sink](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/tree/master/src/test/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/testing) and redirect the input and output for testing.

This topic is also discussed a bit in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/testing.html).