# Flink StreamingEnvronment does not terminate when using Kafka as source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink for a Streaming Application. When creating the stream from a `Collection` or a `List`, the application terminates and everything after the "env.execute" gets executed normally.

I need to use a different source for the stream. More precisely, I use Kafka as a source (`env.addSource(...)`). In this case, the program just block while reaching the end of the stream.

I created an appropriate `Deserialization Schema` for my stream, having an extra event that signals the end of the stream.

I know that the `isEndOfStream()` condition succeeds on that point (I have an appropriate message printed on the screen in this case).

At this point the program just stops and does nothing, and so the commands that follow the "execute" line aren't on my disposal.

I am using `Flink 1.7.2` and the `flink-connector-kafka_2.11`, with `Scala 2.11.12`. I am executing using the IntelliJ environment and Maven.

While researching,  I found a suggestion to throw an exception while getting at the end of the stream (using the Schema's capabilities). That does not support my goal because I also have more operators/commands within the execution of the environment that need to be executed (and do get executed correctly at this point). If i choose to disrupt the program by throwing an exception I would lose everything else.

After the execution line I use the `.getNetRuntime()` function to measure the running time of my operators within the stream.

I need to have `StreamingEnvironment` end like it does when using a List as a source. Is there a way to remove Kafka at this point for example?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441153/how-to-stop-a-flink-streaming-job-from-program

Comment: Thanks you for the response. Unfortunately as the post states itself the `FlinkConnector09 ` has got the Fetcher file. I am using the latest 1.0 Connector.
Because it is noted that it might have some issues, I would be able to use the 0.11 connector. I couldn't find such file that uses this kind of loop. If there was that loop my `isEndOfStream()` function would have worked just like the post suggests...

Comment: Its seems that when using `.addSource(Kafka...).setParallelism(1)` the environment terminates and the execution continues normally.