# Flink: how can pipeline shut itself down gracefully?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on a Flink pipeline with unbounded sources. How can I shut the pipeline down gracefully from inside the pipeline code so that checkpointing etc. works, without calling an external service? `System.exit()` seems too crude and throwing an exception will not work with restarting enabled. (I am cancelling the sources, but that doesn't shutdown the pipeline since the sources are unbound.)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `savepoint`: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/cli/#terminating-a-job.

You can stop your streaming job with savepoint. And later if you want to resume your streaming job, re-start it from the savepoint.

Comment: Added a clarification that I want to shut down the pipeline from the pipeline code itself.

Comment: @js. Do you mean the running streaming pipeline stops by itself? Maybe you can try the answer from Till here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441153/how-to-stop-a-flink-streaming-job-from-program

Comment: I had seen it, but I've only now seen the `try { env.execute(); } catch ...` in the comment. I will try that. Thanks!